# Grid View visible property QML

Tags: gridview, qml, visible

I have  a grid view like  below

```
Rectangle {
    id: middle
    color: Style.bgColor
    GridView {
        id: middleGrid
        interactive: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        delegate: LetterButton {
            width: middleGrid.cellWidth - Style.middle.cellSpace
            height: Style.middle.cellHeight
            visible: main.mode ? false : true
            mainChar: modelData.mainChar

        }
    }
```

On click of a button i am setting  mode to true . This makes buttons invisible. And i have a  button to hide the view . Before hiding the view  in QT mode is set to false so that when the view is show again i get the visible button. But on show only one button is shown. Hope I have made my issue clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code posted is insufficient to diagnose your issue.  It could be that your model only contains one element when the menu is re rendered.  It does not look to be due to the visible property not being set though.

Comment: Changing the width resolved my problem. Not sure about the reason behind it .    Made this change    width: main.mode ? 0 : parent.width